# Assign values to a pointer which was initialised to NULL before

Tags: c, pointers, null

Can someone tell me why do I get this segmentation fault?
Is it because I have set a pointer to NULL and passed it to a function?
Should I use arrays or pointers when I want to send an array to function?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* ComputeFibo(int _size);
void PrintFibo(int* _arr, int _size);


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* arr = NULL; 
    int n = 0;

    printf("Please enter Fibonacci size:"); 
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr = ComputeFibo(n);

    PrintFibo(arr, n);

    return 0;
}


int* ComputeFibo(int _size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int indx = 0;
    int* arr = NULL;

    arr[indx] = 1;

    for (indx = 1; indx < _size; ++indx)
    {
        arr[indx] = arr[indx - 1] + sum;
        sum = arr[indx - 1];
    }

    return arr;
}


void PrintFibo(int* _arr, int _size)
{
    int indx = 0;

    for (; indx < _size; ++indx)
    {
        printf("%d\t", _arr[indx]);
    }
}
```

I would love to get an answer with a good explanation for that.

Comment: `int* arr = NULL;`  `arr[indx] = 1;`, you trying to access null array.

Comment: Unlike python for example, C is not a language where array memory is managed for you. Your code must provide the memory for the array.

Comment: Not to mention `return arr;` would utterly fail as `arr` is declared local to `ComputeFibo` (which capable of returning a pointer), but there is no allocation within the function that would create a block of memory to exist beyond function return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to access index of a `null` pointer.

```
int* ComputeFibo(int _size)
{
    int* arr = NULL;

    arr[indx] = 1; //SIGF
...
}
```

I fixed your code if you want a reference.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void compute_fibo(int *_arr, int _size);

void print_fibo(int *_arr, int _size);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 0;

    printf("Please enter Fibonacci size:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    if (arr == NULL) return 1;

    compute_fibo(arr, n);

    print_fibo(arr, n);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}


void compute_fibo(int *_arr, int _size) {
    _arr[0] = 1;
    _arr[1] = 1;

    for (int index = 2; index < _size; index++) {
        _arr[index] = _arr[index - 1] + _arr[index - 2];
    }
}


void print_fibo(int *_arr, int _size) {
    for (int index = 0; index < _size; ++index) {
        printf("%d\t", _arr[index]);
    }
}
```

output:

```
Please enter Fibonacci size:10
1   1   2   3   5   8   13  21  34  55
```

Comment: Thank you both guys.
So I just want to make sure, I can't use an array (in a pointer form) without allocating a place for it on the heap?
I can't create an array on the stack and put into data?

Comment: You can create a variable wherever you want, it hardly depends on the purpose of your program, the life time of the variable, performance, and so on. For example you can implement this program with Fibonacci array on the stack, but for some `n` you will get **stackoverflow**ed (welcome!)

Answer (score 3):

The problematic statement is:

```
   int* arr = NULL;
```

where `arr` is pointing at NULL and then you assign values to `arr` as if it's pointing to valid memory location.

You could fix it with:

```
   int* arr = malloc(_size * sizeof *arr);
   if (arr == NULL) {  /* error *}
```

and then call `free()` on the returned pointer later.

```
    arr = ComputeFibo(n);
    PrintFibo(arr, n);
    free(arr);
```

Also be aware that `int` can only represent limited values in C. So, for example, if you try to calculate upto 100 Fibonacci numbers, you are likely to run into [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).